# What method gets called before a WebView is closed by owner window?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, webview

I'm working with a webview within a window of a Cocoa application. I would like to retrieve some values using stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString on the webview and save them before the application shuts down. I tried using the applicationWillTerminate but by the time I reach this method, it is too late. I was wondering if there's something built into webview that I've missed or if anyone has an elegant  solution to share.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to save this information, why are you waiting until the app is about to terminate?

Comment: Because the application is unaware of the user's interaction with the webpage and I would like to save the configurations the user left the application with, I can then restore the page the same way the user left it with when the application runs in the future.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer. Just sayin'. :-)